# Is there another wall encompassing the entire of Paradis for Marley to use?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So, another question about Attack on Titan.

So in the Manga, and by extension, the Anime, it is revealed that certain people, Eldian IIRC, are transformed into Titans by injecting them with Titan Spinal Fluid. These people are then thrown off a large object, and transform into Pure Titans a short while later.

Now I got to thinking, Is this large object yet another wall placed on the Island of Paradis? Like the three walls protecting Humanity on the Island itself? Or is this just a staging area for the transformation of people in Pure Titans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an outermost wall in Paradi Island other than Maria, Rose, and Sina. So far it's not known whether it surrounds the entire island or just a portion of it, and its purpose is not clear.

**Speculation**: It could be a staging area for the titan transformations, but more importantly a barrier to prevent them from crossing the ocean.

On the inside covers of the tankōbon volumes are written codes in inverted Katakana, and one of them gives a clue to the walls' origins:

> **In the new world, great walls had previously been prepared.**

Sources:

1. (Japanese) http://shingeki-kyojin.com/archives/26439768.html
2. http://calorescence.tumblr.com/post/51450703198/did-you-know-the-inside-covers-of-the-japanese

Comment: I would think that there is an entire outermost wall, based on the sources that you listed in your answer, surrounding the entire island rather than just one piece being used as a staging area. The Titans, whether it be pure or intelligent would, sooner or later, wonder around the staging area and into the ocean, kind of defeating the purpose of them crossing the ocean.

Comment: @GipsyD Yes I would too, but it's not confirmed.

Comment: 'It could be a staging area for the titan transformations...' Wasn't this confirmed already? I remember chapters showing how the Eldian resistance in Marley was brought there, injected with titan fluid and thrown down the wall as they transformed. Other than that, great answer.